# How do I swap the first and second items in an array of strings?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a list of coordinates in string format that has the longitude and the latitude respectively. I would like to have the latitude and THEN longitude:

```
var str = "POLYGON ((-97.7157864909859 30.406523563068, -97.7165355983688 30.4068866173208, -97.7167879301601 30.406495457696, -97.7168046574092 30.4065112735542, -97.7168203607564 30.406527859154, -97.7168349935064 30.4065451649171))
```

I have stripped the strings of its formatting:

```
let formattedString = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "POLYGON ((", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "))", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
var token = formattedString.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

Now I am trying to flip positions for longitude and latitude so that its:

```
30.406523563068, -97.7157864909859, 30.4068866173208, -97.7157864909859
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to change the array's configuration:

```
var coordinateArray = [String]()
for (index, coordinate) in token.enumerated() {
    if index % 2 == 0 {
        coordinateArray.insert(coordinate, at: index)
    } else {
        coordinateArray.insert(coordinate, at: index)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Flipping the position is ok. But I would suggest to make a Model of Location and store lat & long in it. Store the information in array of Location and use it.

Comment: Use classes in the `CoreLocation` framework to store coordinates.

Comment: I'm not trying to store coordinates @RakeshaShastri

Comment: @Rizwan I am simply trying to flip coordinates for my own purposes. I don't need a model.

Comment: @butter_baby "_I have a list of coordinates in string format_" huh? o.O

Comment: @butter_baby What is resisting you to use -> mutating func swapAt(_ i: Int, _ j: Int)
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more functional approach:

```
let str = "POLYGON ((-97.7157864909859 30.406523563068, -97.7165355983688 30.4068866173208, -97.7167879301601 30.406495457696, -97.7168046574092 30.4065112735542, -97.7168203607564 30.406527859154, -97.7168349935064 30.4065451649171))"
let formattedString = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "POLYGON ((", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "))", with: "")

// split by commas, not spaces, because in the original string, pairs of 
// coordinates are separated by commas
let coordianates = formattedString.components(separatedBy: ", ")

// Here I transform each pair of coordinate into an array with two elements, 
// reverse it, and flatten the whole array
let flipped = coordianates.flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: " ").reversed() }
print(flipped)
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about these functional approaches. Very clean. Thank you +1

Comment: @Sweeper - Will this not reverse sequence of whole string in total ?

Comment: The `$0.components(separatedBy: " ")` inside `flatMap` is an array like `["-97.7157864909859", "30.406523563068"]`. Calling `reversed` on that will only reverse the pair of coordinates. @Rizwan

Comment: @Sweeper - Yes it should be like this as you explained. But when you run this code, the last bit pair in string is coming at 0th& 1st index in array. And first pair (-97.7157864909859 30.406523563068) in string goes to last.

Comment: @Rizwan Found out where the problem is. Fixed now. OP removed all the commas in `formattedString`, which makes the split not work.

Comment: @Sweeper - yes, and if the order of the pair is not necessary then just reversing the array after separating on basis of " " will work.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try this using `swapAt` function,

```
var arr = [30.406523563068, -97.7157864909859, 30.4068866173208, -54.881838371711]
    for(index, _) in arr.enumerated() {
        if index % 2 == 0 && index + 1 < arr.count {
             arr.swapAt(index, index + 1)
        }
    }
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `swapAt(_:_:)`

**Example:**

```
var names = ["Paul", "John", "George", "Ringo"]
names.swapAt(0, 1)
```

This will swap `"Paul"` with `"John"` in array.

**For your specific need**

```
var str = "POLYGON ((-97.7157864909859 30.406523563068, -97.7165355983688 30.4068866173208, -97.7167879301601 30.406495457696, -97.7168046574092 30.4065112735542, -97.7168203607564 30.406527859154, -97.7168349935064 30.4065451649171))"

let formattedString = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "POLYGON ((", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "))", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
var coordinateArray = formattedString.components(separatedBy: " ")

for i in stride(from: 0, to: coordinateArray.endIndex - 1, by: 2) {
    coordinateArray.swapAt(i, i+1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your coordinateArray look like this

```
[-97, 30, -97, 30]
```

then you can say that you want to swipe every two elements. Then you need `stride` method which give you every second index of element in your array (starting with 0) and then you can just use `swapAt` method which swap element with every second index and element with index after it.

```
for index in stride(from: coordinateArray.startIndex, to: coordinateArray.endIndex - 1, by: 2) {
     coordinateArray.swapAt(index, index + 1)
}
```